# How to respond to ignored invitations in Game Center?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

**Is there any way to "timeout" an invitation ?**

I am creating a real-time multiplayer game using Game Kit / Game Center. I have my devices, accounts etc set up, and under normal circumstances everything works great. The part that doesn't work great, is when invitations are ignored.

I use the standard matchmaking view controller for creating matches. I

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc]init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 4;

GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc]initWithMatchRequest:request];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]rootViewController]presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

All this works fine if the "invitee" responds to the invitation in a timely manner. The problem occurs, when the "invitee" *ignores* the invitation. In this situation, the standard matchmaking view controller **waits indefinitely for a response.**

[image: Standard matchmaking view controller waiting indefinitely]

This is a problem and can occur both when the "invitee" uses banners or alerts:

One can easily ignore a banner - if one does not select the banner when it appears, the inviter waits indefinitely.

When an invitation arrives, and the game center notification setting is set to "alerts", then an alert pops up, which the user has no choice but to "decline" or "accept". If he selects "decline" or "alert", then all is well because the inviter is informed. But if the "invitee" presses the "home" button, then the alert disappears, and the the "inviter" is not informed. As a result the inviter again waits indefinitely.

Since this is supposed to be handled by Game Center, there is no api or code for timing out. Since the user uses the same view controller for auto-matchmaking, and for inviting other specific players, it is not transparent exactly which option a player is choosing, so one cannot simply timeout, since one doesn't know what the player is doing until the view controller informs the delegate. **How does one handle this situation ? Is there a way for the "inviter" to be aware of an ignored invitation?**

Comment: I've been wanting this too, and I filed a bug report with Apple today about it.  It's virtually impossible to invite 3 players to a match because the odds of getting all 3 are slim, but all 3 must accept or else the entire match fails because it won't timeout the missing players, nor will it let me cancel the invite to those who don't respond.

Comment: In hindsight I guess what one should do is probably just keep track of how long its been, and if some "flag" indicating that everything is "kewl" hasn't been set, try to roll back or something... I'm not focusing on this at the moment, but once you find the answer please post the solution here! XD